# How to re-design input range slider into a circular knob?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, typography

So if I have a basic slider input that affects different font parameters.
For the time we have raw coded the html so we just have the input sliders with no style, so they are straight.

We were wondering if there was some solution to draw a knob in CSS like in Ableton Live so just a circle with a line inside to show where the value is.

Would it be interesting to bring in an SVG or are there simpler solutions. Also how would I link the parameters to an illustration?

```
<label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="fontSize"/>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="letterSpacing"/>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="lineHeight"/>
    <p class="font_1">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
```

Is there an easy way through CSS just to redesign the slider instead of using Canvas like the example below

```
<div class="cp">
    <canvas width="140" class="nob" data-value="0" data-change="test();"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="cp">
    <canvas width="40" class="nob" data-value="0"></canvas>
    <canvas width="40" class="nob" data-value="81"></canvas>
    <canvas width="40" class="nob" data-value="42"></canvas>
    <canvas width="40" class="nob" data-value="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
html,
body {
    background: #EEE;
    height: 90%;
    font: 13px Arial;
    color: #888;
}
.cp {
    background: #EEE;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 350px;
    width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
    
    border: #DDD 1px solid;
    border-radius: 11px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #BBB,
                inset 0px 1px 0px #FFF,
                0px 1px 0px #999;
}
canvas {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```
// Written by Hakan Bilgin
// https://github.com/hbi99/Canvas-nob

(function(window, document) {
    
    'use strict';
    
    var nob = {
        el: false,
        clickY: 0,
        clickX: 0,
        init: function() {
            var nobs = document.getElementsByClassName('nob');
            for (var i=0, cvs; cvs=nobs[i]; i++) {
                cvs.height = cvs.width * 0.9;
                nob.draw(cvs, true);
                cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', nob.doEvent, true);
                cvs.addEventListener('selectstart', nob.doEvent, false);
            }
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', nob.doEvent, true);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', nob.doEvent, true);
        },
        doEvent: function(event) {
            var _nob = nob,
                bodyStyle = document.body.style;
            switch (event.type) {
                case 'selectstart':
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                case 'mousedown':
                    _nob.el = event.target || event.srcElement;
                    _nob.clickY = event.clientY;
                    _nob.clickX = event.clientX;
                    _nob.orgValue = _nob.el.getAttribute('data-value');
                    bodyStyle.cursor = 'none';
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 'mousemove':
                    if (!_nob.el) return;
                    _nob.el.setAttribute('data-value', (Math.min(Math.max(_nob.clickY-event.clientY + (_nob.orgValue - 50), -50), 50) + 50));
                    _nob.draw( _nob.el );
                    break;
                case 'mouseup':
                    if (!_nob.el) return;
                    _nob.el = false;
                    bodyStyle.cursor = '';
                    break;
            }
        },
        draw: function(cvs, isInit) {
            var ctx  = cvs.getContext('2d'),
                d = cvs.width,
                lw = d * 0.1,
                r = d/2,
                radius = r - lw,
                val = cvs.getAttribute('data-value'),
                deg = (Math.min(Math.max(val/100, 0), 1) * 1.5) + 0.75,
                startAngle = 0.745 * Math.PI,
                midAngle = deg * Math.PI,
                endAngle = 0.251 * Math.PI;
                
            // Clear canvas and defaults
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d, d);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#F90';
            ctx.lineWidth = lw;
            ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            
            // Orange line
            if (val > 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(r, r, radius, startAngle, midAngle, false);
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            // Gray line
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(r, r);
            ctx.arc(r, r, radius, midAngle, endAngle, false);
            ctx.stroke();

            // 
            if (isInit) return;
            var onchange = cvs.getAttribute('data-change'),
                parts, fn;
            if (onchange) {
                if (cvs.fnStr !== onchange) {
                    parts = onchange.slice(0,onchange.indexOf('(')).split('.');
                    fn = window;
                    for (var i=0, il=parts.length-1; i<il; i++) {
                        if (!fn[parts[i]]) return;
                        if (parts[i].indexOf('(') > -1) break;
                        fn = fn[parts[i]];
                    }
                    cvs.fnStr = onchange;
                    cvs.fnObj = fn;
                    cvs.fn = fn[parts[i]];
                }
                cvs.fn.call(cvs.fnObj, val);
            }
        }
    };
    nob.init();

})(window, document);
```

I was wondering if this could simply be done in CSS instead of adding so much JS for the sliders.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you want the user to turn the knob? Would it be a sort of (rough) circular motion with a finger for example? And how would they do it with a mouse?

Comment: You can try something like this: [css tricks: Styling Cross-Browser Compatible Range Inputs with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)